# What is the purpose of the "Color Space" on image texture nodes?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, image

After posting [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/18162/2217) answer, I was told that I should of set the *Color Space* to *non-color*. Hence my question, what is the purpose of the *Color Space* on image texture nodes in cycles? I have not set any of my image texture nodes to *Non-Color Data* and have not noticed any side effects.
The [blender wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Nodes/Textures#Image_Texture) is not too clear on the purpose.

> For most color textures the default of Color should be used, but in case of e.g. a bump or alpha map, the pixel values should be interpreted as Non-Color Data, to avoid doing any unwanted color space conversions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on your color management setting in the Scene Properties Editor, Blender will interpret the colors in an image in different ways, (i.e. apply a gamma curve to it, or adjust the color gamut/saturation of the image^)

Changing the color space to noncolor basically tells Blender to skip that conversion, i.e. a bump map is should not be color-managed.

^ I am greatly simplifying what 'color management' is, but for the purpose of this, I think it's sufficient.

Comment: But a bump map simply uses the value of each pixel for the bumping.  Shouldn't a normal map, which uses the individual red and green color channels to adjust the normals, not be set to non color data?

Comment: A color management system could alter both the luminance and chroma value of a texture. Therefore all non-diffuse texture should technically have the noncolor checkbox enabled.