# Render Conversion (Cycles to Blender Render)

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, conversion

**BIG EDIT**: I have solved this. I just disabled the texture from Cycles and I am manually adding the correct ones.

I have a Blender project I am working on for Christmas, and I had to rig many characters. I rigged them in Cycles Render, but I figured out that if I want a smooth output, I need Blender Render. How do I switch from Cycles Render to Blender Render without deleting the textures? Please respond before the 24th, as I am trying to make this as a Christmas project.

**EDIT**: This question is different than the thought-to-be duplicate because I am only moving the textures, not nodes. I also tried the accepted answer and it did not solve my problem.

Comment: By smooth output do you mean a noiseless render? Rigging isn't connected to which renderer you used so I'm unsure what you mean at the minute.

Comment: There is no easy way to switch render engines in blender. Some manual material conversion is required.

Comment: You raise the samples, there is also a tutorial here on how to remove them in the compositor: http://cgcookie.com/blender/2012/12/10/compositing-cycles-render-passes-blender/

Comment: Read [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/18131/2217) to see how to use textures in the blender internal render.

Comment: When you say that you're only moving the textures, not the nodes, do you mean that you don't use nodes or that you will keep the nodes? If you mean the latter, then you should understand that the material nodes of Cycles are not always compatible with those of Blender Internal, and that Cycles have nodes that don't even exist in Internal.

Comment: @MrSquer it would be better if you share your solution in here