# xps model hair transparency in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency

I'm having problems with texturing a model in cycles (blender 2.72b). I downloaded the model and it comes with 3 tga files per section. see image below for the hair for example[image]

I render in cycles. I search the forums, but i still can't get the transparency right. How do I set this up with nodes?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: that's it!! Thank you! I found out that the purple image is the bump mapping(?) :)

Comment: [This](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/18162/2217) answer will help explain what to do with the other image maps