# Where is the image Mapping tab?

Tags: uv

I am following this tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=il7ajiCepus
(note at the 3:12 mark in the video is where the step I need help is) 
I need to put a logo onto a trophy I made in Blender. I am following all the way to the point where in the tutorial he says to switch the mapping to UV. But I dont see a "mapping" window like his. I have Image Mapping, but no plain Mapping window. I really need help to get this done. I am on a deadline for a championship football game film. I got the trophy all set, I only need to get it textured and get this logo on there and I can finish.

[image: missing mapping window]

Comment: could be because you do not have a texture selected on your object

Comment: In the tutorial Blender internal is used, in cycles you control textures with material nodes

Comment: I see, I missed that he was in Blender Render not Cycles. Ok, well do you know any good tutorials I can follow to learn the function with nodes you are talking about. I am very new to Blender and Nodes is something I have barely scratched the surface on.

Comment: @NathanDion see my answers (BI and cycles) to [this question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/18129/2217).

Comment: Awesome!! I can see the logo now on the plane!!! Progress is good :) Thank you David. Let me fudge around with it now and see if thats all there is to it :)

Answer (score 4):

This is because you're using Cycles, but the tutorial you linked is for Blender Internal Render. You can switch to BI by going to the 3D view's header and, to the left of the Blender logo, using the combo box to select *Blender Render*.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for all the question editing you do around blender.stackexchange.  I'm curious as to why you always edit out the "thank you"s at the end of questions.  Thanks.

Comment: That's because I'm mean :P No, just kidding; it has been [discussed on meta](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/466/editing-questions-to-remove-thank-you-etc), and I think the conclusion is that it doesn't add any information to the question, and since the point of SE is to exchange knowledge, it should be removed. Take a look a the meta post I linked and if you disagree, we can discuss it there.