# Load .dll texture plugin

Tags: texturing, add-on

How can I load .dll texture plugin? I read this thread https://www.blender.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2684 but it didn't help - I can't find any "load plugin" button.

Answer (score 1):

First off, the forum you linked to was talking about version **2.3x**. (If you look at the post's dates it was from 2004!) We are using 2.77 now, a lot has changed.

Back then, and up till **2.4x** you could use texture plugins. There is no way to use a .dll texture in blender now.
There is [OSL](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/osl.html) scripting in cycles, so you could recode one if you really want to.

Now a days, textures are used a little differently. See my answer to
[How are texture maps imported into Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/18129/2217) for how to import image textures in cycles, and blender internal.