# Blender Importing . How to reapply all textures and maps to Luxox18 import models?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, import

Im looking for help to reapply textures and maps to models from r6 siege game  in Cycles Render.
I downloaded his imported models from his Devian (link below) and i imported .obj file , but i have no idea how to reapply specular,normal and detailed normal maps. Only what i've got is diffuse texture but no clue how to reapply other textures :

Here's the link to the character im trying to use:
http://luxox18.deviantart.com/art/Rainbow-Six-Siege-Tachanka-650518471

I hope someone can help me with this , because node setting is a painful and hard thing in blender :(

(ps): if someone had time to make whole node tree for this model i would be so glad for it , cause i want to use other models too :)

Comment: This is such a general question that would be best served by reading a manual. This [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cb4U_WFln-w) video is quite short and should get you more than far along:

Comment: [How are texture maps imported into Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/18129/2217)