# I want to combine several textures... Bump, displacement, diffuse, specular but I don't know the node combination. A screenshot would be nice

Tags: texturing, node-editor

I have 4 textures. Bump, displacement, specular and diffuse. Please what node combination would help me get the best render for this mixture. A screenshot after the node setup would be nice.

Comment: The Mix shader is to mix nodes.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/18162/2217

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood the question here the answer

With the powerful addon **Node Wrangler in built in Blender** you can set the node automatically.

Make a folder and paste all the images (Bump, displacement, diffuse, specular).

With the Principle BSDF Node selected Press Ctrl+Shit+T

A pop-up which need to access all the images made above folder. Select all (Press A)

Press Principle BSDF Setup and your done . Render it with F12

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just use new principled shader ([Tutorial](https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/2017/6/21/how-to-use-blenders-new-ultimate-shader-principled-bsdf)):

[image]

And if you want to use displacement, you can connect it directly to material output node.