# OBJ files: How to subdivide materials for model?

Tags: materials, objects, geometry, object-mode

The model in this OBJ file (https://poly.google.com/view/534TY_Ie4jz) contains one material.

Is it possible to import the file in Blender, then "cut up" or divide the material into different sections?

Specifically:

1) If we want to make the stick red but the top of the popsicle green, there's no way to do this because it's all one material.
Changing the material color changes the color for the entire popsicle. Is it possible to change red to green?

2) If we want to subdivide the red area into an arbitrary number of subareas, is this possible? For instance, could we turn the red area into 5 subareas of different colors?

Comment: You can assign materials to specific vertices, probs what you want

Comment: @VRM Thanks so much! What if we want to divide the popsicle into an arbitrary number of materials? For instance, if we want to divide the red area into 5 subareas, is this possible? Or are we constrained by the mesh?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can do this, with Materials, or with the Texture. 
In Blender you can add materials and assign then where you select the mesh (Click [Here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh/748) to see a similar question)

Or you can also keep only one material and customize the image texture that comes with the .obj When you download the model check out a small image that contains 4 colors, that's the image texture for the model.

In case you have any questions about assigning texture in Blender check

[This](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18129/how-are-texture-maps-imported-into-blender) for Blender Internal

[This](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8697/how-do-i-put-an-image-texture-on-a-material-in-cycles) for Cycles

[image] Image texture

[image]

Since the model already has a UV mapping, you only need a 2D Image Editor *(Photoshop, GIMP, etc..)* Then you can change the colors for your desired parts.

[image]

After saving that image, in Blender, on the UV Editor, click Image > Reload Image

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! What if we want to divide the popsicle into an arbitrary number of materials? For instance, if we want to divide the red/green area into 5 subareas, is this possible? It's unclear from the answer you linked. Or are we constrained by the mesh?

Comment: You can edit the texture to make those areas to change color

Comment: @Crashalot It's possible, in this case the model only uses 4 colors, that's why the image texture is so small and its actually just a color palette. So if you want more colors and divisions you will need a new color palette that has more colors, and also you will need to modify the mesh and make a new uv mapping to properly assign the new colors. _(see the example on the actual mesh, all of the divisions and parts are uv mapped and separated according to each color)_

Comment: @Mateus thanks for the fast reply. when you say "see the example on the actual mesh" which example are you referring to?

Comment: @Crashalot I'm referring to the popsicle model

Comment: Thanks, okay, so you have to create a new mesh. Would Blender, for instance, let you subdivide the red/green part of the mesh into 20 elements, or do you have to create a new mesh from scratch?

Comment: @Crashalot Its not necessary to create a new mesh, to subdivide you can just add some loop cuts and then assign different colors to it