# How to import textures for premade model?

Tags: mesh, materials

I have a model downloaded from the internet that comes with textures as .png and I turned the model itself into a .blend (originally a .pmx) but I can't seem to figure out how to place the textures that came with it. If someone could help me that would be great! (also if there is a way just to straight up import the model with the textures at all once please tell me)

Comment: see mycomment here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98716/why-is-blender-not-importing-material-and-uv-morphs-shape-keys-from-mmd-models#comment174815_98716

Comment: [How are texture maps imported into Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/18129/2217)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself, you just need to push the “shadeless” button in the menu to the right of the screen, it’s hidden until you push the arrow to show it.